# Using acmsmall document class,

Tags: footnotes, titles, acm

Using `acmsmall` document class, below is the minimal working example (you need [`acmsmall.cls`](http://www.acm.org/publications/latex_style/) in the folder):

```
\documentclass[prodmode,acmtkdd]{acmsmall}

  \markboth{Jenkinson et al.}{Optimal Search for Data Patterns}

  \title{Optimal Search for Data Patterns\thanks{This work
  was supported by Marine Institute and by European Union
  under Grant No. 3000.}}

  \author{ABRAM JENKINSON and CHRISTIAN ANDERSON
  \affil{University of Great Britain}}

  \acmformat{Abram Jenkinson and Christian Anderson. 2014.
  Optimal Search for Data Patterns}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\end{document}
```

The text in `\thanks` does not appear anywhere, but the small `1` appears like if it would be "..Data Patterns<sup>1</sup>". How to make it appear?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Edited my question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\thanks` is only stored in `\@thanks`, which is never executed within the class's definition of `\maketitle`. You can add this to the end `\maketitle` by the following addition to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\maketitle}{\@thanks}
\makeatother
```

It's just added as a regular footnote.

[image]

```
\documentclass[prodmode,acmtkdd]{acmsmall}

  \markboth{Jenkinson et al.}{Optimal Search for Data Patterns}

  \title{Optimal Search for Data Patterns\thanks{This work
  was supported by Marine Institute and by European Union
  under Grant No. 3000.}}

  \author{ABRAM JENKINSON and CHRISTIAN ANDERSON
  \affil{University of Great Britain}}

  \acmformat{Abram Jenkinson and Christian Anderson. 2014.
  Optimal Search for Data Patterns}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\maketitle}{\@thanks}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are violating the style intended by the [`acmsmall`](http://www.acm.org/publications/latex_style/) document class. There's no mentioning of the `\thanks` macro in its guide. It actually says this (section `2.4` of *acmsmall Author Submission Guide*):

> The bottom of the article’s title page contains acknowledgment of
>   support, the author(s) address(es), a “permission to copy” statement,
>   and a line containing a copyright symbol (c) along with the copyright
>   information.. This is all entered with a bottomstuff environment;
>   there must be no blank line after the \begin{bottomstuff} command.

You should, in other words, not use `\thanks`, but the environment `{bottomstuff}`.